# How to prove that the categorical definition of subgroup generated by a subset in Aluffi's book is well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

In Aluffi's book "Algebra: Chapter 0", he uses the [categorical definition of free group in pp. 71](https://books.google.com/books?id=deWkZWYbyHQC&pg=PA71&dq=Algebra:+Chapter+0+%22A+free+group+F(A)+on+A+will+be%22&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij4Pu9uuPaAhXDx4MKHVHIASYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Algebra%3A%20Chapter%200%20%22A%20free%20group%20F(A)%20on%20A%20will%20be%22&f=false), also see in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Universal_property). This defines the free group up to group isomorphism. This is easy to get through.

---

Now the problem is, he also use this to define the [subgroup generated by a subset in pp. 81](https://books.google.com/books?id=deWkZWYbyHQC&pg=PA81&dq=Algebra:+Chapter+0+%22Example:+Subgroup+generated+by+a+subset%22&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjicXlu-PaAhVBxoMKHdrNC-sQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Algebra%3A%20Chapter%200%20%22Example%3A%20Subgroup%20generated%20by%20a%20subset%22&f=false). I put it here:

> **Definition (Subgroup generated by a subset).** Let $G$ be a group. If $A\subset G$ is any subset, we have a unique group homomorphism
>   $$\varphi_A: F(A)\to G,$$
>   by the universal property of free group. The image of this homomorphism is a subgroup of $G$, the *subgroup generated by $A$* in $G$, ofter denoted $\langle A\rangle$.

This will naturally lead to a doubt of the well-definedness, i.e., does this definition depend on the choice of the free group $F(A)$ that is unique up to group isomorphism?

---

I don't know how to prove it to be well-defined. What I know is that if one can prove the well-definedness, then it's easy to prove that the categorical definition of generated subgroup is equivalent to other two definitions which just follows the categorical one in Aluffi's book, see also [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Generated_Subgroup).

Can anyone give some clues or hints on the well-definedness? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ F'(A)$ be some other free group which is isomorphic to $F(A)$ via $ \psi$. Let $ \varphi_A'$ be the unique homomorphism $ F'(A)\rightarrow G$. We also get a homomorphism from $ F'(A) \rightarrow G $ by taking $ \varphi_A\circ \psi$. By uniqueness, these are the same homomorphism, so
$$\varphi_{A'}(F'(A))=\varphi_A\circ \psi(F'(A))=\varphi_A(F(A))$$
where the last equality follows from the fact that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I guess the more interesting point is that both $\phi$ and $\phi'$ have the same image.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Is this right: $\varphi_A'(F'(A))=\varphi_A\circ\psi(F'(A))=\varphi_A(F(A))$?

Comment: I think what we would like to say more is that the group homomorphism $\varphi_A\circ \psi: F'(A) \rightarrow G$ is exactly the one such that the diagram in the definition of free group $F'(A)$ commutes.

Comment: I have edited my proof slightly to include this equality, which is correct @Q.Huang. I think that this is enough to show that the image of both homomorphisms is the same, which is what you need to show well-defined.